# jQuery DOM traversal in each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a simple DOM transverse in an each loop. The issue is that jquery is selecting multiple instances of the specified class instead of the one I'm trying to select using $(this). This is my markup:

```
@foreach ($details as $i)
  <tr>
    <div class="ajax-tracking-check">
      <input type="hidden" name="trans_id" value="{{ $i->transaction_id }}"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="tracking" value="{{ $i->tracking_number }}"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="carrier" value="{{ $i->shipping_carrier }}"/>
    </div>
    <td class="td-image">{{ HTML::image($i->image_url, 'item-image', array('class' => 'sir')) }}</td>
    <td>{{ $i->item }}</td>
    <td>${{ $i->price }}</td>
    <td>{{ date('M d, Y',strtotime(Transaction::where('transaction_id', $i->transaction_id)->pluck('created_at'))) }}</td>
    <td class="breh">
      {{ $i->tracking_number }}
      <!-- </br> -->
      {{ $i->shipping_carrier }}
    </td>
    <td class="status"><h2>{{ $i->status }}</h2></td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

I'm trying to select the class ".breh" with this line in my js:

```
var field    = $(this).parent().find('td.breh');
```

This is the entire function:

```
   $('.ajax-tracking-check').each(function() {

      var number   = $(this).find('input[name="tracking"]').val();
      var trans_id = $(this).find('input[name="trans_id"]').val();
      var carrier  = $(this).find('input[name="carrier"]').val();
      var field    = $(this).parent().find('td.breh');

      $.post(
        'purchased/ajax/tracking/check',
        {
          trans_id: trans_id,
          number:   number,
          carrier:  carrier
        },
        function(data) {
          if (number !== "1")
          {
            // field.text(data['city']+', '+data['state']);
            field.addClass('red');
          }
        }
      );
  });
```

The first instance table row's var number is equal to 1 BUT the second row is equal to a random string. With my if statement, I'm trying to add the class "red" but it's added to both instances of "field".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML is not valid.

Your ".ajax-tracking-check" DIV is not contained by a TD inside the table and because of that on the statement

```
var field = $(this).parent().find('td.breh');
```

The parent() is returning the BODY element and after that the find() returns all of the .breh element ocurrences.

You should wrap that DIV on a TD element (you can hide it with a display:none) and then the statement would be

```
var field = $(this).parents('tr').find('td.breh');
```

Note the plural of "parents()", this will go up in the parents chain until it finds the element TR not just one level as with the singular "parent()"